# How to Load Related Objects in EF?

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, lazy-loading

I have 3 models in EF Code First:

```
public class Book
{
 public int Id { get; set; }
 public ICollection<Author> Authors{ get; set; }
}

public class Author
 {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "")]
  [ForeignKey("AuthorName")]
  public int AuthorId{ get; set; }
  public User AuthorName{ get; set; }
  public bool Signed {get; set;}
  }

public class User
 {
 public int Id { get; set; }
 public string Name{ get; set; }
 }
```

I use this code for select all AuthorName of BookId .

```
db.Book.Find(BookId).Authors.Where(e => e.Signed == false);
```

But AuthorName is null for this.

How  to Load Related Objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will load everything in one query:

```
from b in db.Book
where b.Id == BookId
from a in b.Authors
where !a.Signed
select a.AuthorName.Name
```

The fluent equivalent is

```
db.Books.Where(b => b.Id  == BookId)
        .SelectMany(b => b.Authors.Where(a => !a.Signed)
        .Select(a => a.AuthorName.Name)
```

The statement `db.Book.Find(BookId)` loads one `Book` from the database. After that, you can only load `Author`s and `User`s by lazy loading. `Find` can't be combined with `Include`.

Comment: I shouldn't even attempt code with a New Year hangover. Removed my answer. +1 on yours.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO even your `Authors` should be empty because you don't have your entities setup for lazy loading. If you make `Authors` and `AuthorName` virtual your query should work but it can cause up to 3 separate queries to database.